# SQL Statement - optimisation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sgtn
 WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT kun_id
                         FROM sgtn, kun
                        WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS)
                              AND sgtn_kun_id = kun_id)

       AND sgtn_strasse IN (SELECT sgtn.sgtn_strasse
                              FROM sgtn
                             WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT kun_id
                                                     FROM sgtn, kun
                                                    WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS)
                                                          AND sgtn_kun_id = kun_id)

                             GROUP BY sgtn.sgtn_strasse
                            HAVING COUNT(sgtn_strasse) > 2);
```

`LONG LIST OF EMAILS` is i.e.:
'abc@domain.com',
'def@domain.com',
.
.
.
'xyz@domain.com'

As you can see I repeat some part of subquerys in this query.

I'm wondering if and how can I replace `LONG LIST OF EMAILS`. It occurs in my statement twice. Would it be possible to edit this query, so that the mentioned `LONG LIST OF EMAILS` occurs once?

Comment: Replace your subquery's and IN's with joins, they can achieve the same results in this case and are *much* more efficient. Easier too once you know how they work.

Comment: Also: why are those emails directly in your query? Aren't they stored in the same database? If your query should retrieve them, not contain them literal

Comment: can you explain what are trying to return using query above?

Comment: @dtech: a join and a sub-query with IN are **not** equivalent.

Comment: @dtech: as a_horse_with_no_name said, i wanna check only a subset of my entries.

Comment: You can still do that with JOIN's (WHERE and such...), but if you'd just provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use

```
IN (SELECT DISTINCT kun_id
    FROM sgtn, kun
    WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS)
    AND sgtn_kun_id = kun_id)
```

it is enough

```
IN (SELECT kun_id
    FROM kun
    WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS))
```

the rows having multiple sgtn_strasse and email in your list can be detected with

```
select * from (
  SELECT s.*, count(*) over (partition by sgtn_strasse) cnt_strasse
  FROM sgtn s
  WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT kun_id
                       FROM kun
                       WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS))
  )
WHERE cnt_strasse > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a WITH clause:

```
WITH kun_list AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT kun_id
      FROM sgtn, kun
     WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS)
           AND sgtn_kun_id = kun_id)

SELECT *
  FROM sgtn
 WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT kun_id
                         FROM kun_list)

       AND sgtn_strasse IN (SELECT sgtn.sgtn_strasse
                              FROM sgtn
                             WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT kun_id
                                                     FROM kun_list)

                             GROUP BY sgtn.sgtn_strasse
                            HAVING COUNT(sgtn_strasse) > 2);
```

Comment: This responds(correctly) strictly to email list duplication, but offer no performance improvement, 'cause it's essentially the same query as in OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with CTE as (
SELECT sgtn.*, count(sgtn_strasse) OVER (PARTITION BY sgtn_strasse) cnt
FROM sgtn
WHERE sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT kun_id FROM kun 
                      WHERE kun.kun_e_mail IN (LONG LIST OF EMAILS))
)

SELECT * FROM  CTE WHERE CNT > 2
```

Comment: two things to correct: `sgtn_kun_id IN (SELECT *` part and in cte is no column `kun_id`.

Comment: It's ok now, esentially the same answer as mine :)